# How can I enforce TLS in sendmail when I don't necessarily know the hostname of the downstream MTA (only IPs)? [e.g. by recipients' domain]

Tags: email, smtp, sendmail, security, starttls

I'm running SendMail 8.14 and have some custom static routes for sending to certain domains.  These domains are "internal" but not managed directly by me.

Here's an example of `/etc/mail/mailertable`:

```
fooexample.com          esmtp:[1.1.1.1]:[2.2.2.2]
```

The idea here being that I always want to try sending to 1.1.1.1 first and only send do 2.2.2.2 if the primary is unavailable.

This works great. It even uses opportunistic TLS.  Woohoo.

I now want to *enforce/require* STARTTLS encryption when sending to this domain.  That way, if I'm sending to 1.1.1.1 and they somehow don't have TLS, I won't let the message through.

I've implemented this policy for external domains in the past and historically have just added this to `/etc/mail/access`:

```
TLS_Clt:exampledomainname.com ENCR:112
```

(where examplehostname.com is a part of the MX/A record hostname for a system -- not necessarily the email domain... since email can be handled by cloud services these days).

Annnnnyway, I'm not sure if this will work for my new scenario because I'm using a static route and not resolving MX/A records (which is what I thought `TLS_Clt` was ultimately looking at.)

So my questions are:

1) What exactly is `TLS_Clt` looking for in the matching pattern and how does it verify this if I'm specifying a static route?

2) Can I simply add `TLS_Clt:fooexample.com ENCR:112`?  Or should it be something like

```
TLS_Clt:1.1.1.1 ENCR:112
TLS_Clt:2.2.2.2 ENCR:112
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short version:

Use `TLS_Rcpt` access table entries. to specify per recipient's domain requirements.

```
TLS_Rcpt:fooexample.com ENCR:112`
```

### Full version:

0) `TLS_Clt` is for **incoming** connections.  Use `TLS_Srv` for **outgoing** connections
1) Sendmail looks for `TLS_Srv` access table entries based on `$&{server_name}` first and `$&{server_addr}` later.
2) `TLS_Srv:fooexample.com ENCR:112` will not do what you want (in every case)
You may use `TLS_Rcpt`to specify per recipient or recipient's domain requirements in access table

Comment: Ah! That's great information, thank you.  Does `TLS_Rcpt` support partial matches?  For example, will `TLS_Rcpt:fooexample.com ENCR:112` work for email going to bob@subdomain.foo.com, jane@subdomain2.foo.com and david@foo.com?

Comment: The entry will cover subdomains too.  You may check yourself sequence of access map lookups using the following test command `echo "tls_rcpt user+detail@host.example.net" | sendmail -d60.5 -bt`

Comment: BTW there is non sendmail.org sendmail.cf extension to require SSL key with specific md5 checksum (The key may be not registered in public CA).

Comment: I have a few more questions because I'm curious (thanks for your patience). 1) Could I technically have an entire email address if I wanted to just match a single recipient?  For example, would  `TLS_Rcpt:bob@fooexample.com ENCR:112` only require tls when sending to bob@fooexample.com and NOT require TLS when sending to joe@fooexample.com?   2) Where does Sendmail pull `$&{server_name}` and `$&{server_addr}`? Is that determined via reverse dns lookup?  Or is it pulling it from the `EHLO` value?

Comment: 1) Yes you can specify requirements for specific email address using `TLS_Rcpt`. It is "Is established connection good enough for sending messages addressed for X?" 2) I do not know (I suspect reverse DNS). The Bar Book is not precise enough, I do not have time to check the source.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a ruleset for sender address? I didn't see one. I guess that makes sense because the enveloper sender wouldn't be provided until after a TLS session was established.

Comment: I do not remember such ruleset.  It could work in mode "is connnection good enough for messages from X?".